# Debian: How to delay configuration when installing/upgrading?

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

One of my Debian systems is rarely upgraded. So when it is time to upgrade, there are loads of packages. Right now I basically have to monitor the upgrade, because every 50 packages or so there is a package that needs help deciding if it should keep the config or have a new configuration put in.

My system is really slow, so I would prefer if I could tell the system to deal with as many packages as it can on its own and leave the rest for me.

So what I am looking for is something similar to `make -k` but for `apt-get` or `aptitude`. What I am not looking for is non-interactive configuration of packages: I *do* want to configure the packages, but I want the system to install/upgrade as many packages as it can before asking me to configure anything. That way I hope to return later, configure a bunch of packages, and the install the remaining (hopefully) few packages.

Edit:

Also it would be nice that when I *do* return to configure that I can get to configure as many as possible. So it should start by postponing all packages that need configuration and when I return it should prioritize all packages that can be configured at this point.

Comment: If you just run `apt-get` with the `--assume-yes` option, does it show something on the console to indicate which packages are getting default config? If so, you could install everything and then just `dpkg-reconfigure` the defaulted ones after.

Comment: If the upgrade is 500 packages (which is not unrealistic) I really do not want to go through a log file manually to cleanup. I would rather it skipped those packages than installing overwriting with the default.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you asked; asking the config questions afterward:

```
$ DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical
$ export DEBIAN_PRIORITY
$ apt-get upgrade
# Wait a long time.   Should be almost entirely noninteractive.
$ dpkg-reconfigure --default-priority=medium --unseen-only
```

Alternatively you could try asking all the config questions before:

```
$ apt-get clean
$ cat >> /etc/apt/apt.conf <<EOF
// Pre-configure all packages before
// they are installed.
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {
    "dpkg-preconfigure --apt --priority=low";
};
EOF
$ apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I just tested on another old system:# dpkg-reconfigure --default-priority=medium --unseen-only
Option default-priority does not take an argument

Comment: Tested on another server (a Lenny). PHP-ini blocked with a dialog box.